# Delete files and folders by date using SHFileOperation

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-shell

I'm trying to write a program that will delete a set of files/folders that are matching a specific naming pattern (wild cards) based on their dates using the windows API

```
...

    SHFILEOPSTRUCT shFileOpStruct = {
            .hwnd   = NULL,
            .wFunc  = processByDate->op,
            .pTo    = NULL,
            .fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_SILENT
    };

    buildReferenceDate( &refTime, processByDate->nDays );
    hFind = FindFirstFile( processByDate->srcFileName, &findFileData );
    errorCode = GetLastError();

    while ( errorCode == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
        LONG res = CompareFileTime( &refTime, &findFileData.ftCreationTime );

        if ( (processByDate->nDays ^ res) > 0 ) {
            sprintf( strrchr(processByDate->srcFileName, '\\') + 1, "%s%c",
                                             findFileData.cFileName, '\0');
            shFileOpStruct.pFrom = processByDate->srcFileName;
            fprintf( stdout, "\n%s\n", shFileOpStruct.pFrom);
            fprintf( stdout, "\n0x%x\n", SHFileOperation( &shFileOpStruct ));
        }
        FindNextFile( hFind, &findFileData );
        errorCode = GetLastError();
    }

    if ( errorCode != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES )
        displayError ( stdout, errorCode );

...
```

Only the first matching file is deleted, because FindNextFile terminates with "The handle is invalid." apparently SHFileOperation somehow invalidates the file handle (or at least so I suppose). The only solution I can think of is to save the name of the matching files/folders and delete them one by one. Is there any other simpler solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread's last error code is not set when a function succeeds. Instead of calling `GetLastError`, you have to check the return value of `FindNextFile`.

> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero and the lpFindFileData parameter contains information about the next file or directory found.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero and the contents of lpFindFileData are indeterminate.

[FindNextFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28VS.85%29.aspx)

The loop should look like this:

```
HANDLE handle(FindFirstFile(...));
if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        // filter files here
    }
    while (FindNextFile(handle, ...));
    FindClose(handle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    FindNextFile( hFind, &findFileData );
    errorCode = GetLastError();
```

That's wrong.  *Only* call GetLastError() when you get a FALSE return from FindNextFile().  Fix:

```
    if (!FindNextFile( hFind, &findFileData ) {
        errorCode = GetLastError();
    }
```